# Get SQL records based on XML attribute values

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery

I have done some basic XML querying using T-SQL but I am not sure how to attack this problem.

I would like to query all rows in a table where a specific XML attribute has a requested value.

Here is my table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Applications_Submissions]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SubmissionGuid] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [TestMode] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [SubmissionID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Status] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProcessId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Version] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ReturnUrl] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
    [Applications] [xml] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedByUser] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DateCreated] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [DateDeleted] [datetime] NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [FG_Applications]
) ON [FG_Applications] TEXTIMAGE_ON [FG_Applications]
```

The XML data stored in the `[Application]` column is structured like this:

```
<Submission xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Id="15" TestMode="false" SubmissionId="15" Status="0" ProcessId="0" Version="1" CreatedByUser="2" DateCreated="2016-09-28T15:08:25.667" DateDeleted="0001-01-01T00:00:00">
  <ReturnUrl>/Register/RegistrationData/Register/1094/1/[SGUID]</ReturnUrl>
  <SubmissionGuid>f1891c84-1fda-41b4-a78b-605bfdcaf45a</SubmissionGuid>
  <Applications>
    <Application ApplicationID="15" ApplicationName="Test Form">
      <FriendlyUrl>test-form-1234</FriendlyUrl>
      <Pages>
        <Page PageId="16" ApplicationId="15" ViewOrder="0">
          <PageTitle>Page 1</PageTitle>
          <Fields>
            <Field FieldId="26" FieldType="10" ViewOrder="0">
              <FieldTitle>Who are you</FieldTitle>
              <FieldValues>Jeffrey</FieldValues>
              <FieldsResponses />
              <PossibleFieldValues />
            </Field>
            <Field FieldId="27" FieldType="0" ViewOrder="0">
              <FieldTitle>Why are you here?</FieldTitle>
              <FieldValues />
              <FieldsResponses />
              <PossibleFieldValues />
            </Field>
            <Field FieldId="28" FieldType="5" ViewOrder="0">
              <FieldTitle>Pick any</FieldTitle>
              <FieldsResponses>
                <FieldsResponse FieldResponseId="19" LinkToApplication="0" ViewOrder="0" Selected="false">
                  <Response>One</Response>
                </FieldsResponse>
                <FieldsResponse FieldResponseId="20" LinkToApplication="12" ViewOrder="0" Selected="false">
                  <Response>Two</Response>
                </FieldsResponse>
                <FieldsResponse FieldResponseId="21" LinkToApplication="0" ViewOrder="0" Selected="false">
                  <Response>Three</Response>
                </FieldsResponse>
              </FieldsResponses>
              <PossibleFieldValues />
            </Field>
          </Fields>
        </Page>
        <Page PageId="17" ApplicationId="15" ViewOrder="0">
          <PageTitle>Page 2</PageTitle>
          <Fields>
            <Field FieldId="29" FieldType="6" ViewOrder="0">
              <FieldTitle>Agreement</FieldTitle>
              <FieldsResponses>
                <FieldsResponse FieldResponseId="22" LinkToApplication="16" ViewOrder="0" Selected="false">
                  <Response>I agree</Response>
                </FieldsResponse>
                <FieldsResponse FieldResponseId="23" LinkToApplication="16" ViewOrder="0" Selected="false">
                  <Response>I disagree</Response>
                </FieldsResponse>
              </FieldsResponses>
              <PossibleFieldValues />
            </Field>
          </Fields>
        </Page>
      </Pages>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
</Submission>
```

I would like to get the table rows based on the `ApplicationID` attribute that is stored in the `<Application>` node. Each `<Submission>` can have multiple `<Application>` nodes.

What is the best way of doing this?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best for this was `xml.exist()`. But this will **never** be fast... If you need this more often or with bigger counts of rows you should rather extract the ApplicationIDs together with the actual rowID into a side table. This can be done in a trigger.

But you might try this:

--Mock-up table

```
DECLARE @Applications_Submissions TABLE(Id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,TestText VARCHAR(MAX),Applications XML);
```

--Insert two mock-up rows

```
INSERT INTO @Applications_Submissions VALUES
('Contains ApplicationID 15, 16 and 100'
 ,N'<Submission xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Id="15" TestMode="false" SubmissionId="15" Status="0" ProcessId="0" Version="1" CreatedByUser="2" DateCreated="2016-09-28T15:08:25.667" DateDeleted="0001-01-01T00:00:00">
  <Applications>
    <Application ApplicationID="15" ApplicationName="Test Form">
      <FriendlyUrl>blah 15</FriendlyUrl>
    </Application>
    <Application ApplicationID="16" ApplicationName="Test Form">
      <FriendlyUrl>blah 16</FriendlyUrl>
    </Application>
    <Application ApplicationID="100" ApplicationName="Test Form">
      <FriendlyUrl>blah 100</FriendlyUrl>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
</Submission>')
,('Contains ApplicationID 15, 17 and 200'
  ,N'<Submission xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Id="15" TestMode="false" SubmissionId="15" Status="0" ProcessId="0" Version="1" CreatedByUser="2" DateCreated="2016-09-28T15:08:25.667" DateDeleted="0001-01-01T00:00:00">
  <Applications>
    <Application ApplicationID="15" ApplicationName="Test Form">
      <FriendlyUrl>blah 15</FriendlyUrl>
    </Application>
    <Application ApplicationID="17" ApplicationName="Test Form">
      <FriendlyUrl>blah 17</FriendlyUrl>
    </Application>
    <Application ApplicationID="200" ApplicationName="Test Form">
      <FriendlyUrl>blah 200</FriendlyUrl>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
</Submission>');
```

--This is, what you are searching for

```
--Try different values (15 returns both rows, 16, 100 or 200 just one row and any other value none
DECLARE @ApplicationID INT=15;
```

--And this is the query

--*Btw: I use wildcard-namespace to avoid confusion with your actual namespaces...*

```
SELECT Id
      ,TestText

      --This is just to show, how you would fetch a value from the given ApplicationID
      ,Applications.value('(/*:Submission/*:Applications/*:Application[(@*:ApplicationID)[1] eq sql:variable("@ApplicationID")]/*:FriendlyUrl)[1]','nvarchar(max)')

FROM @Applications_Submissions
WHERE Applications.exist('/*:Submission/*:Applications/*:Application[(@*:ApplicationID)[1] eq sql:variable("@ApplicationID")]')=1
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked like a charm. I ended up creating the table to store the applications as they came in via an INSERT/UPDATE trigger.